# Ошибка при использовании await

Tags: c#, async-await

Немного переделала.

Ошибка  CS0029  Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "CookComputing.XmlRpc.XmlRpcStruct" в "System.Threading.Tasks.Task".

```
 private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//КНОПКА ОБНОВИТЬ
    {
        obnovit();
    }


    public async void obnovit()  //
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < kol; i++)
        {
            int idv = idvseh[i];
            vse[ii] = await obnovit1(idv);
            ii = ii + 1;

        }

    }

    public Task<XmlRpcStruct> obnovit1(int idv)
    {
            object[] arr = proxy.get(idv);
            XmlRpcStruct arr3 = (XmlRpcStruct)arr[3];
            return arr3;// теперь здесь ошибка
    }
```

Comment: Какую версию .NET Framework используете?

Comment: Метод proxy.get какой тип возвращает?

Comment: Тут либо .Net<4.5, либо proxy.get не асинхронный.

Comment: тип видимо не асинхонный(

Comment: покажите пжлста сигнатуру метода get у объекта proxy. Иначе данный вопрос требует помощи телепата. И да, из описания ошибки видно, что метод get возвращает массив объектов, причем здесь await?

Comment: при том, чтобы одновременно несколько запросов выполнялись

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас в описании ошибки все написано. Метод proxy.get() возвращает массив объектов, а результат выражение после await должнен реализовывать метод GetAwaiter() (утиная типизация)
Если очень хочется, то сделайте асинхронную обертку, что то типа этого:

```
 public Task<XmlRpcStruct> ObnovitAsync()
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<XmlRpcStruct>();
        Task.Run(() => {
            var result = this.obnovit1();
            tcs.SetResult(result);
        });

        return tcs.Task;
    }
```

Метод Obnovit очень режет глаза, может быть лучше Update

Comment: и каким образом можно этого добиться?

Comment: Зачем тут TaskCompletionSource? Почему сразу результат Task.Run не возвращать?

Comment: Здесь возможно не принципиально, но вообще можно к примеру сделать кэш и сразу возвращать результат, если данные, получаемые по id не изменяются

Comment: Ваш приём мне помог! Огромное вам спасибо. Ошибка устранилась.Но теперь у меня происходит путаница при записи пришедших результатов в массив))

Comment: записываю в стек, а потом из него в массив - работает

Comment: работает. но очень медленно

Answer (score 1):

Судя по тому коду, что вы представили, вам вообще тут не нужна асинхронность. И вы либо убираете ее везде:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//КНОПКА ОБНОВИТЬ
{
    obnovit();
}

public void obnovit()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < kol; i++)
    {
        int idv = idvseh[i];
        vse[ii] = obnovit1(idv);
        ii = ii + 1;
    }
}

public XmlRpcStruct obnovit1(int idv)
{
        object[] arr = proxy.get(idv);
        XmlRpcStruct arr3 = (XmlRpcStruct)arr[3];
        return arr3;
}
```

Либо делаете `proxy.get()` асинхронным (если это возможно) и "протягиваете" асинхронность через все методы:

```
private async void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//КНОПКА ОБНОВИТЬ
{
    // try/catch нужен, иначе ошибка тут может обрушить приложение или вы вообще о ней не узнаете
    try
    {
        await obnovit();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }
}


public async Task obnovit()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < kol; i++)
    {
        int idv = idvseh[i];
        vse[ii] = await obnovit1(idv);
        ii = ii + 1;
    }
}

public async Task<XmlRpcStruct> obnovit1(int idv)
{
        object[] arr = await proxy.get(idv);
        XmlRpcStruct arr3 = (XmlRpcStruct)arr[3];
        return arr3;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Нужна. так как один запрос длится примерно 300 мс, а их несколько сотен.. что с ошибкой делать Ошибка CS0029 Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "CookComputing.XmlRpc.XmlRpcStruct" в "System.Threading.Tasks.Task".  не понятно

Comment: @404 а зачем вы пытаетесь преобразовать XmlRpcStruct в Task?